# Fast algorithm to determine a new array ordering from an array of indices

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Suppose we start with some array of indices. I want some function

```
int* getOrdering(int* idxs, int len);
```

which is equivalent to this process (in pseudocode):

```
input: int* idxs, int len
std::vector<int> a = {1,2,...,len+1};
out = {0,...,0}; // empty initialized array with length len
n = 0;
while n < len:
    out[n] = a[idx[n]]; // first iteration sets out[0] to a[idxs[0]] = 4.
    a.erase(a.begin() + n);
    ++n;
```

For `getOrdering({3,0,0,2,0}, 5)`:

| `n` | `idx[n]` | `a` | `out` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `3` | `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` | `{4}` |
| `1` | `0` | `{1,2,3,5,6}` | `{4,1}` |
| `2` | `0` | `{2,3,5,6}` | `{4,1,2}` |
| `3` | `2` | `{3,5,6}` | `{4,1,2,6}` |
| `4` | `0` | `{3,5}` | `{4,1,2,6,3}` |

I was wondering if anyone has a better algorithm than this for finding this ordering, because my application will be running this in the order of `O(len!)` times. We can always assume the indices input are are always correct and will never result in error, i.e. `idx[n]` is always in the range `[0,len-n)`.

Further, does the vector erase operate in `O(1)`? If not, is there a better data structure to use to keep this process to `O(1)`?

Comment: Does the vector order matter?  If it doesn't, you can swap with the back element, then pop_back.

Comment: its not quite clear if your indexing takes into account the shrinked size of `a`, ie after calling erase on it, some elements, which before were at index `i` are then at index `i-1`. (on the other hand, if not, you wouldn't need `a` in the first place). Can you show example input and example output?

Comment: @Eljay It matters, if we swapped it would change the order of the output.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I did show an example in the last paragraph, and yes we can assume the indices are always correct, i.e. `idx[n]` is always in the range `[0,len-n)`,

Comment: The `output {4,1,2,6,3}` does not seem correct to me....

Comment: @CiaPan It is correct, I added a worked solution.

Comment: I think you can avoid actually creating any intermediate containers by calculating the indices directly. I am just not sure how to do that efficiently. For example `3 0 0 ...` becomes `3 0 1 ...` because you know that there is `1` index `<= 0` before that `0`, while `3 0` need not change

Comment: how big is `len` ? Erasing middle elements from a `std::list` is cheaper than erasing from a `std::vector`, but then a `std::list` is often worse overall

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That's what I've been trying to consider, and the solution I'm looking for will be an analytical solution like this I imagine.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number len will probably range from 4-30.

Comment: @FloydEverest I would not worry about the algorithmic complexity of a `std::vector<int>` for ranges smaller than a few hundreds elements at a minimum (depending on the algorithm, a few tens of thousands, even).

Comment: @Frank this process is being called O(len!) times, so even if the complexity of `a.erase(a.begin() + n);` is O(len), it increases my function complexity to O(len^2), so the overall program complexity becomes O(len!len^2). Hence why it's important to improve it to O(len), or even O(len log(len)).

Comment: @FloydEverest, Sorry, I should have been clearer. Finding a better algorithm is absolutely worthwhile. It's replacing the `std::vector<>` for some other container because `erase()` is not O(1) while keeping the same algorithm that's not worth it at the scales being discussed.

Comment: @Frank Oh! That makes more sense - my bad for jumping to conclusions.

Comment: Maybe you might change your `O(len!)` algo to produce array directly usable. Which is a magnitude of `len` BTW?

Comment: Is that program failing if i pass the input ```{0,0,0,0,0,3},5``` even it is valid according to your condition **idx[n] is always in the range [0,len-n)**

Comment: @RoshanM: `a[5] >= 6 - 5`, so invalid.

Comment: Can you have a routine that converts the ordering into an indexing?  So `{3,0,0,2,0}` would become `{3,0,1,4,2}`?  That would allow you to avoid the erase overhead.

Comment: @Eljay any algorithm which produces a correct output in under O(n^2) is an improvement - how would you convert the input into an indexing like that? And from that indexing how would you obtain the output?

Comment: @Jarod42 I have attempted this, but any attempt of mine required an increase in memory complexity of O(len!*len). Memory is more constrained than time for me in this case.

Comment: `O(len!)` make think you want to iterate over permutations, [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) exists. and there are in SO code for `next_combination`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `vector` vs. `list` makes no difference here. `a.erase()` would be faster, but `a.begin() + n` would be slower by the same amount.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes and no - I'm traversing a permutation tree, and I need the corresponding permutation at each leaf.

Comment: @Jarod42 for which there is a very simple recursive method outlined [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/), which actually solves my issue... However, I'm going to leave this question open for people who may wish to solve a similar issue in the future, since it appears not to have been asked before.

Comment: The reason it hasn't been asked before is that it's not a common problem.  Usually when you have a list of indexes, those indexes don't assume the array they're indexing will be shrinking as you work with it.

Comment: Actually if I use the method I linked earlier, will need the exact inverse to the function I described earlier, so I wonder which is easier.

Comment: @FloydEverest: You might be interested by that [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8aafab8919c23e5) with [next_partial_permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61402151/2684539).

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, you want to create an array telling what rank in an ascending order each element of the input array `idx` has.

For this you can simply *sort* the `idx` array, during which you perform exactly the same copy/move/swap operations on `a` which are performed on `idx`. Then for all `0 ≤ i ≤ len–1` set `output[a[i]] = i`, which is 'at the original position of each value store its sorted position'.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the possible solution, can you show how this works for the example I gave? For that example, I believe the sorted indices for `{3,0,0,2,0}` is `{4,0,1,3,2}`, which isn't the correct solution. Am I correct?

Comment: So I must have misunderstood your needs. :(